# adminhtml/html_select preselect

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, select

I'm searching for a solution with the magento buildin way to create html select blocks. Using magento CE 1.9.0.1

My code is:

```
$this->setChild('designs',
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/html_select')
            ->setData(array(
                'id' => 'product_option_{{id}}_design',
                'class' => 'required-entry select-type-design'
            ))
    );

    $this->getChild('designs')->setName('product[options][{{id}}][design]')
        ->setName('product[options][{{id}}][design]')
        ->setOptions($options);
```

$options is a array of the possible selectoptions.

How can I make one option to be selected?

I can see the functionality in the code /var/www/geschenkidee/web/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Html/Select.php in the proteced method _optionToHtml. But I dont see a way to set this infomation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `value` element in the array you set as data.

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/html_select')
        ->setData(array(
            'id' => 'product_option_{{id}}_design',
            'class' => 'required-entry select-type-design',
            'value' => 'Your value to be selected here'
        ))
```

Comment: So I "only" have to find out how to get the saved attribute in my custom product option.

Comment: Yes. You only need that

Comment: Seems to be done with some javascript... There is no way to get on the productdate in the customoption tab options.

Comment: Ok it's working. Instead of adding the selected value in the block it has to be done in a ugly JS like all the other customoptions are be done: /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml